# How to permanently change Scrollback?

Tags: kubuntu, konsole

Question:
How to permanently change Scrollback from
1000 Lines to
9999 Lines?  or more

In Terminal, right click, Adjust Scrollback.
1000 Lines = Fixed size, current Adjust Scrollback - Konsole

notice says:
Any adjustments are only temporary to this session.

​
using:
Kubuntu 22.04.1 (Jammy Jellyfish)
konsole 21.12.3

--

Answer (score 0):

- Menu: *Settings*

  - *Edit Current Profile…*

    - Left column: *Scrolling*

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is there another way to arrive at ```Left column: Scrolling``` ?
Because my screen does not show ```Edit Current Profile…```